# What Junk in Fallout 4 isn't really junk?

Tags: fallout-4

Some items are labeled junk and have a list of constituent materials. For example a baseball is made of leather and cork. But you need an actual baseball to make a baseball grenade.

Does anyone have a list of junk items used in recipes before they are broken down?